# Access SQL executed through excel returns an empty result set

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a single table in an excel spreadsheet with around 20 columns and I wrote a SQL query in EXCEL using ADO to retrieve a result set I am after.

I self join a table like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT C1.[Column1], C1.[Column2], C2.[Column 1], C2.[Column 2] FROM [Data 1$] C1 " & _
         "INNER JOIN [Data 1$] C2 on C1.[Column 3] = C2.[Column 3] " & _
         "AND C1.[Column 1] = C2.[Column 1] " & _
         "AND C1.[Column 2] = C2.[Column 2] " & _
         "AND (C1.[Column 4] = RIGHT(C2.[Column 5], LEN(C2.[Column 5])-1) " & _
         "OR C2.[Column 4] = RIGHT(C1.[Column 5], LEN(C1.[Column 5])-1)) " & _
         "AND C1.[Column 6] < C2.[Column 6]"
```

However, the result is an empty set. I drilled it down to the following line

```
"AND (C1.[Column 4] = RIGHT(C2.[Column 5], LEN(C2.[Column 5])-1) " & _ 
"OR C2.[Column 4] = RIGHT(C1.[Column 5], LEN(C1.[Column 5])-1)) "
```

If I remove it I get 5 results, 3 of each meet this criteria!!

Do you think you can help me figure out what's going on?

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure you single-quote any strings values in the WHERE clause.  You should edit your question and show us the output of `Debug.Print strSQL`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to complete a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks guys. Here is the Debug Print output:                                         `code`SELECT C1.[Column 1], C1.[Column 2], C2.[Column 2], C2.[Column 3] FROM [Worksheet 1$] C1 INNER JOIN [Worksheet 1$] C2 on C1.[Column 4] = C2.[Column 4] AND C1.[Column 1] = C2.[Column 1] AND (C1.[Column 5] = RIGHT(C2.[Column 6], LEN(C2.[Column 6])-1) OR C2.[Column 5] = RIGHT(C1.[Column 6], LEN(C1.[Column 6])-1)) AND C1.[Column 2] < C2.[Column 2]`code`

Comment: Looks like you're not putting the excel ranges in [SheetName$range] as c1 for example

Comment: damn, shoulda' refreshed that page :D

Comment: Can you post the complete SQL?  I cant see the WHERE's that people are referring to.  It may be the OR in the join not working, have you tried it using the UNION of the 2 separate joins to see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

+1 on @Alex K. said. However, I dont see stuff like `WHERE c1.[Column1] = 'Henry'` in your SQL, so i suppose that is not the actual mistake here.

Additionally you might check the following:

1. In your code I see column names written like `[Column 2]` and like `[Column2]` (with+without blanks). You didn't mention an error (which would normally state that a parameter is missing), so i suppose the typos are only in your post - but no harm in double checking.
2. You got some substring-checks in your `WHERE`-claus with `Right(...)` and such. Any chance you you got trailing-blanks in your strings?
3. Explictly Format your columns as numbers or text. Then, like @Alex K. mentioned, enclose String-Filters in single quotes `'`. This get's a bit messy if paired with VBA-variables, but this doesn't seem to be an issue here.
4. Having formatted your columns, make sure the corresponding columns in `C1` and `C2` are of the same type. Again, normally you would get an Error stating something like "Datafield has the wrong data type" - still no harm in checking.

In general: since you write your SQL in Excel-VBA, you could consider writing your SQL-code into an empty excel-sheet, then read it into a a VBA-String variable like so:

```
i = 1
While Not IsEmpty(wsSQL.Cells(i, 1))
    strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & " " & wsSQL.Cells(i, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

The obvious disadvantage is that you can't use VBA-Variables. However,

- accessibility/readability is far better
- you needn't worry about escaping double quotes `"`
- there's no max. number of code lines (25 in VBA-Code)

hope that helps